# can I put index.php in a subdirectory, but not display subdirectory in url?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a website, say http://mysite.com.  I would like to put index.php in a subdirectory,  `public_html/mysubdir/index.php`.  I would like `public_html/mysubdir/index.php` to get executed when the user goes to http://mysite.com.  And I would like the url to continue to read `http://mysite.com`.  Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, search here for URL rewriting.

Comment: what http server you are using?

Comment: @Ivan:  I am using Apache 2.2.22.  Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite rules *may* be overkill for this depending on what you want.  For just your main index page, this will work...

Simply adding this one line to your `.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex mysubdir/index.php
```

It will display the page located at `mysubdir/index.php` while simply showing `http://mysite.com` in the URL.

I use this method myself.  While **all** of my pages are located in the same subdirectory, the home page is displayed with my domain name by itself (`http://www.mysite.com`).  All other pages show the full URL.

---

If you also have `index` pages within deeper subdirectories and want those to come up by default within the subdirectory.

Example:

If you want this page:  `http://mysite.com/mysubdir/anothersub/index.php`

to come up with this URL:  `http://mysite.com/mysubdir/anothersub/`

Then modify the line with another `index.php` like this...

```
DirectoryIndex mysubdir/index.php index.php
```

What this does is tell the server to look for files with those names in that same order.  If it can't find the first, it tries the second, and so on.

When you're inside your root at `/` it finds and then displays `mysubdir/index.php`.

When you're inside another subdirectory like `/mysubdir/anothersub/`, it can't find anything named `mysubdir/index.php` so it goes to the next item and displays `index.php`

Comment: This works, thank you.  However, now I have another problem.  index.php links to various css and js files, using relative links.  For example: <script src="js/jquery-1.2.1.js" type="text/javascript">.  The relative links work fine if user goes to http://mysite.com/mysubdir/index.php.  But they are not working if user goes to http://mysite.com.  Any ideas?

Comment: I simply use "absolute" links. `/mysubdir/js/jquery-1.2.1.js`, etc.  Everything with respect to the document root at `/`.

Answer (score 5):

If your webserver is Apache you could use [URL rewriting with mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).

Another option is to create an index.php in the root directory and include index.php in the sub directory.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a .htaccess file and define `Rewrite` rules.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Make sure that `mod_rewrite` is enabled and then place .htaccess file in your root directory with something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ your_subdir/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Great! I'm glad it was useful.